# How do I pass a string as a function argument in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, function, arguments

Basically, I have 10 data files and I wrote a MATLAB function to process these data.
The code is like this:

```
function Z = fitdata(file_path)

  A = importdata(file_path,',');
  ...

end
```

Since I don't want to input the same command 10 times (for different file names), I wrote another script to automate this processing. The code looks like this:

```
function X = automate()

  myarray = {'file_one', 'file_two', 'file_three',......,'file_ten'};
  for i = 1:9
    mypath = myarray{i};
    W = fitdata(mypath);
    ...
  end

end
```

But I'm getting the error "Too many input arguments" at the call to the fitdata(file_path) function.

How should I do this?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. it was 'importdata' im my code. 
But I'm still getting the error. I even tried to type fitdata('file_one',',') from Matlab command-line, but the error persistes.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything overtly wrong with your syntax. Are you sure that `importdata()` isn't choking on your file? Try `importdata('my_file_1', ',')` on the MATLAB command line.

Comment: importdata() is OK. If I declare a string like : file_path ='filename' and call importdata(file_path,',') then it works.
I think the only problem is how to pass a string as argument to a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since the suggestions below didn't solve the problem, and since there doesn't appear to be anything else wrong with the code you posted, I would next check to make sure the version of `fitdata` given above is the *only* function of that name on the MATLAB path. You may have inadvertently created another function or script and saved it as `fitdata.m`, and this may be getting called instead of the version you created above.

---

*Previous answer:*

I think you mean to use the [IMPORTDATA](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/importdata.html) function instead of [IMPORT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/import.html), which is the likely source of the error you are getting.

One additional piece of advice: it's best not to name one of your variables `path`, since there is already a function [PATH](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/path.html). The variable will end up being used instead of the function (based on the [MATLAB precedence rules](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f10-60956.html)), which will still be what you want to happen in this specific case but is a source of confusion and error in other cases.