# How to input string in a Matlab function

Tags: string, matlab, function

I want to write a function that loads a text file and plots its content with time. I have 20 text files so I want to be able to choose from them.

My current not working code:

TextFile is a generic variable
text123.txt is the actual name of one of the files i want to load

```
function []= PlotText(TextFile)


text(1,:)=load('text123.txt') ;

t=0:10;

plot(t,text)

end
```

I appreciate any help!!

Comment: Could you say why it's not working?  Do you get an error message?  From what you've written, I think you could have `text(1,:)=load(TextFile);` and call your function as `PlotText('text123.txt');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a string as a function argument in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989919/how-do-i-pass-a-string-as-a-function-argument-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

use importdata instead of load with appropriate delimiter. I assume you used Tab.

```
filename = 'num.txt';
delimiterIn = '\t';
text = importdata(filename,delimiterIn)
t=1:10;
plot(t,text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can also use dlmread if your file contains only numeric data separated by the same symbol (called a delimiter) such as a comma (,), semicolon (;), space ( ), or tab (   ). This would look like:

```
function []= PlotText(TextFile)


text(1,:)=dlmread('text123.txt');

t=0:10;

plot(t,text)

end
```

Keep in mind that your code is written in a way that expects the contents of text123.txt to have 11 values in a single row. Also, if you are using multiple files, then I suggest having the file name be another input to the function:

```
function []= PlotText(TextFile,filename)


text(1,:)=load(filename) ;

t=0:10;

plot(t,text)

end
```